# emacs loads foo.zip in archive-mode correctly but not the same file renamed to foo.qzv

Tags: file, emacs, zip

I have some zip files with suffix `.qzv`. I'd like to load them into emacs like zip files in archive-mode; however, I can't change their file names. So I added `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.qzv\\'" . archive-mode))` (and I confirmed that `auto-mode-alist` has an entry of `("\\.qzv\\'" . archive-mode)`). when I open a foo.qzv files, it is opened as binary gibberish. It gave me error like this:

`File mode specification error: (args-out-of-range foo.qzv 3129008734 3129008738)`

Intriguingly, when I copy the file to foo.zip, it can be perfectly loaded as archive-mode. What am I missing here?

I am using the latest emacs version: `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.8) of 2019-04-13`

Comment: If you open the file with no special configuration and then manually enable archive-mode, what happens?

Comment: @RandyMorris, I got the same error when manually doing `M-: (archive-mode)`

Comment: I can open a `.qzv` file that is just a renamed `.zip` file with `emacs -Q`, no `auto-mode-alist` edits necessary. Is it definitely a real zip file?  What does the `file` command say?

Comment: it is definitely a zip file. I can `unzip foo.qzv` and `file foo.qzv` gives `foo.qzv: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract`

Comment: Note that there is an entry in `magic-fallback-mode-alist` which ought to detect zip files even when the filename is unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Learned from @jpkotta's suggestion, I found it fine to open qzv file with `emacs -Q`. Then I tested my emacs config part by part and found the culprit is this:

```
 (use-package unicad
   :load-path "misc/")
```

After removing it, it is fine to open zip file with any suffix.

Comment: yes. I added it long time ago for non-utf8 chinese files (if I remember correctly)